# How to handle show window when the main window is closed on dock?

Tags: swift, macos

I have handled when the window is minimized, and not visible, but how do i handle show window when the window is closed? sorry for this newbie question

I've tried creating a new window but it would crash after i close

```
@objc func showMainWindow() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
            
            var windowsCount = 0
            for windows in NSApp.windows {
                if windows.isMiniaturized {
                    windows.deminiaturize(self)
                }
                
                if !windows.isVisible {
                    windows.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
                }
                windowsCount+=1
            }
            print(windowsCount)
            if(windowsCount <= 2){
                print("window closed")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nswindow+crash+closed

Comment: figured it out, simple answer is to stop using the default window, make your own window controller